# Change paragraph text from another html site

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple html site with some text and a php-login area. When logged in successfully (which already works) I come to a site where I want the possibility to change paragraph text on the landing page.

I tried this code, but I lets me only change paragraph text on the same site, not on the landing page. Is this possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() {
document.getElementById("name2").innerHTML = "New text inside the text element!";
    }
```

Button to trigger the event

```
<input id="button1" type="button" value="1" onclick="change()">
```

Comment: I recommend you look into *sessions* if you're using `php` to try and achieve this

Comment: Changes need to be sent to server and stored there. Then landing page would need to be set up to output the stored data

Answer (score 0):

well, document refers to the site, not the landing page, right?
besides, if you want to make a change permanent, you should retrieve the text from somewhere you save it in, and not only change what is currently displayed

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely pass a cookie to the Global session variable and you can use an if statement to check on the new page if the session is available and then you can render a new markup.

```
<?php
  // Start the session
  session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
  // Set session variables
  $_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
  $_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
  echo "Session variables are set.";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

if you set these variable then you can have access to them on each page and can use it to manipulate your data